# To find out the records which are not updated?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

How do i find find out which records are processed and which ones are not?

Example :

```
update oppar 
set oppar_run_mode = 0, 
    oppar_run_time = 0, 
    oppar_interval_ind = 'N' , 
    oppar_destination = '',
    oppar_run_date ='', 
    oppar_run_interval='' 
where (oppar_job_name = oppar_job_rec) and (oppar_job_rec in 
(
'CSCLM',
'ARCLEVEXT',
'ARCLEVUPD',
'ARCLSAEXT',
'ARCLSACA',
'ARCLSACL',
'ARCLSAAG',
'ARCLSAGN',               
'ARCLSAWO',
'ARCLSALN',
'ARCLSASU',
'ARCLSACBL',))
```

if i get like two rows updated.Especially
I want the exact names of oppar_job_rec(CLCLM,ARCLEVEXT and so on) which are not updated.

`Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production`

Answer (score 4):

You could consider using [`RETURNING INTO`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) clause. Here is a small test I had performed.

```
create table test3 (
    flag1 VARCHAR2(2),
    id NUMBER
);

insert into test3 values ('A', 1);
insert into test3 values ('A', 2);
insert into test3 values ('A', 3);
insert into test3 values ('A', 4);
insert into test3 values ('B', 5);
```

Update I issue is:

```
update test3  set id = id +10
where flag1 = 'A'
```

This will update 4 rows.

Below PL/SQL block returns `flag1` column of 4 updated rows:

```
DECLARE
TYPE vat is table of varchar2(2) index by pls_integer;
vatt  vat;
begin
    update test3  set id = id +10
    where flag1 = 'A'
    RETURNING flag1 BULK COLLECT INTO vatt;
    FOR IDX IN VATT.first .. VATT.LAST
    loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VATT(IDX));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The result shows is:

```
A
A
A
A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider auditing, but it will add additional costs.
Following this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/audit.htm)